# Duplicate of photos?

Tags: photos.app

Given latest versions of MacOS and iOS and one iMac and one iPhone both on the same iCloud account.

I take a picture with the iPhone. It shows up, via photo stream on the iMac. So far so good.

Now I attach the iPhone to the iMac and do a sync. Does the photo now "live natively" on the iMac or still just through photo stream? I think it's not native yet.

Now I use Photos app on iMac and import the photos from the iPhone. Now the photo lives natively on the iMac but it looks like I have a duplicate because the stream copy of it is also there.

That can't be right can it?

Answer (score 1):

I would not sync, so no this isn’t right IMO. Use iCloud if you want to sync photos between a Mac and an iPhone is my advice.

Comment: Not too helpful. I have too many pictures and dont want to pay apple every month

Comment: Fair enough. I gladly pay Apple $30 a year so I don’t have to micromanage things. I figure my time is more valuable to me than the cost to pay for simplicity. If you don’t see the value, do not pay for the service. Is too many 100k photos or more @pitosalas